# Создание службы Windows на C# в Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, service

В коммерческой версии студии есть стандартный шаблон создания Windows Service, а вот в Express такого шаблона нет, и он не доступен онлайн.

С полгода назад видел статью как создать службу в Express редакции, но сейчас не могу её найти. Если у кого осталось или кто-то помнит как это делается, опишите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MS Visual Studio 2013 Community точно есть такой шаблон, а так только кодом думаю надо писать

Comment: Интересует именно редакция Express...

Comment: Тогда попробуй так https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/426b649d-842c-40cf-b666-71c88fb4689d/windows-service-template-missing-in-vs-2013-express?forum=vssetup

Comment: Хотя не понимаю, чем Community не устраивает

Comment: Ну или вот так вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569606/how-can-i-make-service-apps-with-visual-c-sharp-express

Comment: Коммерческое использование...  Спасибо, второй вариант выглядит тем что нужен.